# jQuery AjaxSubmit not firing on IE9

Tags: json, jquery, post, internet-explorer-9

I'm submitting a normal aJaxSubmit request. It works perfectly on FireFox and Chrome.

However, on IE9 it does not work. It only goes as far as the "beforeSubmit" and it successfully completes the pre-callback submit, then it does nothing.

IE9 developer tools show NO post to process.php

Here is my code:

```
                $("#mainForm").validate({
            rules: {

        // This looks for the html artibute name="CaseSensitiveNameHere"
        // Also the inital element being validated is case sensitive to whatever the html arrtibute is. So if it is name="EMAIL", then you must set the function below to EMAIL: { function } required: 'EMAIL'.
        name: {
            required: "name", // this means that the "name:" field must return the value == the "Name" function above - also it must have the same name as itself - so Name must have a function called Name
            required: true // this makes "null" or emtpy invalid
        },
        email: {
            required: 'email', //this means that the "Email:" field must return the value == the "Email" function above - also it must have the same name as itself - so Email must have a function called Email
            required: true,
            email: true // this makes "null" or emtpy invalid
        },      

        webinarDate: {
            required: true
        },      
        webinar_date: {
            required: true
        },      

        webinar_time: {
            required: true
        }       

    }, // End Rules



    messages: {
        Name: "Enter Your First Name",
        Email: "Enter A Valid Email",
        webinarDate: "Choose A Webinar Time"
    },
    onfocusout: false,

    //errorElement: "div",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) { 
    element.parent("td").prev("td").html(''); // Clears placeholder text in previous <td> element
    //$(".errorBox").html(''); //Clears the text in #errorBox1 for error text to be placed there
    error.appendTo( element.parent("td").prev("td") ) // places error text in previous sibling <td> element! woo yes! haha 2/4/11
    //error.appendTo(".errorBox") // places error text in #errorBox1
    .css('font-weight', 'bold'); // sets css for -  error.appendTo so its error.appendTo.css


    // other Error based scripts here!



},
   success: function(label) {
     label.addClass("valid").text("").removeClass("error");

            },



            submitHandler: function(form) {
            jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit({
                type: "post", // sets the method to POST (default is GET) if no "method" attribute is found on the <form> tag!!!
                url: "process-autopilot.php",                   
                crossDomain: true,
                dataType: "json",   
                beforeSubmit:  showRequest(), // run the BEFORE SUBMITTING CALLBACK aka Function - check if email is set to example@gmail.com, if true, return false, else, return true and go head and submit!
                success: function(data, textStatus){ //do stuff

} });
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: In case any update you found on this topic, please share

Answer (score 0):

Is compatibility mode on or off?

Have you tried setting IE8 standards with:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

Comment: I've tested through Developer mode (F12) putting into IE9 compatibility mode, as well as IE8 - it still does not submit.